# Is it possible use column name instead of number as in a function passed to apply?

Tags: r, apply

I would like to apply a function to each row of a `data.frame/data.table`

```
cases <- expand.grid(a=c(TRUE,FALSE), b=c(TRUE,FALSE), c=c(TRUE,FALSE))

myFun <- function(data, row){
  otherFun(data, row[1], row[2], row[3])
}

apply(cases, 1, myFun, data=dt1)
```

This works, however,

```
myFun <- function(data, row){
  otherFun(data, row$a, row$b, row$c)
}
```

This doesn't work.

What's the best way to do it so that it doesn't have to depend on column orders?

Comment: Don't use `$`. `[` works with names as well as positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` coerces things to a matrix. See Details in `?apply`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

So $ indexing isn't appropriate.